# How can i access to user data on Facebook using API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm working on an application that requires fetching user data from Facebook using API calls, specifically, I'm interested in retrieving the user's profile picture. I have already created an App on Facebook's developer platform and have set the necessary permissions. Additionally, I possess the access token required for making API requests.

However, I'm uncertain about the steps involved in sending a request to the user from my app to obtain permission for accessing their profile picture. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me through the process or provide a code example that demonstrates how to achieve this.

To summarize, my main questions are:

How do I initiate a request to the user from my app to grant permission for accessing their profile picture?
What API endpoint(s) and parameters should I use to obtain the necessary permissions specifically for accessing the user's profile picture?
Are there any specific permissions I need to request from the user to access their profile picture?

```
import requests

# Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with the actual access token you obtained
access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# Replace 'USER_ID' with the user's ID or 'me' if you want to get the authenticated user's profile picture
user_id = 'USER_ID'

# Make the API request to get the profile picture
url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?type=large&access_token={access_token}'
response = requests.get(url)

# Process the response or save the picture
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('profile_picture.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print("Profile picture saved successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch profile picture. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

I attempted to access the profile picture using my own account, and the process was successful. However, I encountered difficulties when trying to obtain permission from other users and use their user ID to fetch their profile data.

To address this issue, I sought guidance on the steps to obtain permission from users other than myself and subsequently utilize their user ID to retrieve their profile information, specifically the profile picture.

The solution involves implementing the Facebook Login flow to acquire permission from other users, obtaining their access token upon successful authentication and authorization. With the user's access token, I can retrieve their unique Facebook ID, enabling me to construct an API call and fetch their profile picture